# filter custom post type archive page using meta_query with multiple arrays using acf relationship field

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

As the title suggests I'm trying to filter a custom post type archive page using meta_query with multiple arrays using an acf relationship field.

This is what I have so far using the documentation and tutorials at acf. Both the keywords filter and the project_ref filter work independently if I use 'relation' => 'AND' but only keywords works using 'OR' and never together. Also, project_ref is a post id.

```
 // functions.php
   $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

        // allow the url to alter the query
        if( !empty($_GET['keywords']) OR !empty($_GET['project_ref']) )
        {
          $keywords = explode(',', $_GET['keywords']);
          $projects = $_GET['project_ref'];

          // Add our meta query to the original meta queries
          $meta_query[] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
              'key'   => 'keywords',
              'value'   => $keywords,
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
              'key' => 'project_ref',
              'value' => $projects,
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
          );
        }
```

So if my url is website.com/customposttype/?keywords=one,two&project_ref=684 the posts filter by the keywords but not the project_ref post id. I also get an error *Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in .../wp-includes/meta.php on line 1400*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm close but I definitely seem to be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could be using the wrong compare value for your keywords portion of the query.

As per the [WP_Query codex entry](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> value (string|array) - Custom field value. It can be an array only
>   when compare is 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'. You don't
>   have to specify a value when using the 'EXISTS' or 'NOT EXISTS'
>   comparisons in WordPress 3.9 and up.

As your error is indicating you're passing an array. In SQL when you want to check for the existance of a number of required values you would use the IN compare option.

So your code would be:

```
 // functions.php
   $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

        // allow the url to alter the query
        if( !empty($_GET['keywords']) OR !empty($_GET['project_ref']) )
        {
          $keywords = explode(',', $_GET['keywords']);
          $projects = $_GET['project_ref'];

          // Add our meta query to the original meta queries
          $meta_query[] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
              'key'   => 'keywords',
              'value'   => $keywords,
              'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
              'key' => 'project_ref',
              'value' => $projects,
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
          );
        }
```